# List<T>.Add Doesn't add to the list

Tags: c#, winforms

Well the problem is that my count on the list is not rising so it's not adding the object to the list.

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

private void addEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    employees.Add(new Employee()
    {
        egn = egnInput.Text,
        names = namesInput.Text,
        proffesion = professionList.Text,
        office = officeList.Text,
        salary = Double.Parse(salaryInput.Text),
        joinDate = DateTime.Parse(joinDatePicker.Text)
    });

    MessageBox.Show("Служителя бе добавен успешно!");

    egnInput.Clear();
    namesInput.Clear();
    professionList.Text = "";
    officeList.Text = "";
    salaryInput.Clear();
    joinDatePicker.Text = "";

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think `new` does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have defined the `List` in `addEmployee_Click` event and so every time you click the `Button` the `List` is created again. You should remove the following line in your `addEmployee_Click` event because you have already declared it globally:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

Comment: Correct! He has `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();` outside the method which defines a (non-static and private) __field__ on the class. And he has `List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();` inside the method which declares a __local variable__. So there are two things called `employees`. In such a case, saying just ,`employees.Add(...)` leads to the local variable. To access the field (class-level variable), you must say `this.employees.Add(...)` in such cases. Of course, once you get rid of the local variable, you do not have to say `this.` because no ambiguity exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't define the list inside `addEmployee_Click`, rather make it global like below:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>(); // make this global to the class

private void addEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employees.Add(new Employee()
    {
        egn = egnInput.Text,
        names = namesInput.Text,
        proffesion = professionList.Text,
        office = officeList.Text,
        salary = Double.Parse(salaryInput.Text),
        joinDate = DateTime.Parse(joinDatePicker.Text)
    });

    MessageBox.Show("Служителя бе добавен успешно!");

    egnInput.Clear();
    namesInput.Clear();
    professionList.Text = "";
    officeList.Text = "";
    salaryInput.Clear();
    joinDatePicker.Text = "";
}
```